# How to Add Tax to Paypal IPN Checkout

Tags: paypal, checkout, paypal-ipn

I've tried adding the "tax" field, however nothing tax related shows up in my checkout. How do I add the tax amount to my checkout for Paypal?

Comment: Can you clarify which paypal service call you are talking about? IPN is generally about payment notification, is this express checkout? if so the field name is taxAmt.

Answer (score 7):

I'm guessing you found an answer by now, but for the sake of the other people finding this question through Google:

If you're trying to add tax to a shopping cart, the variable name changes from "tax" to "tax_cart", as so (for 8% tax):

```
<input type="hidden" name="tax_cart" value="<?php echo number_format(($price * 0.08),2); ?>">
```

Comment: Just found this answer, and found it very helpful.  Where in the paypal IPN documentation does it actually mention this?  I was frustrated for almost 2 hours because the documentation only said to set "tax", not "tax_cart", and your answer is the only one I found googling that mentions to use tax_cart rather than tax.